# Which chiral carbon do L and D in L- or D-glucose refer to?

Tags: stereochemistry, chirality

I see and D- and L- glucose are mirror images of each other. and I understand D and L are for chirality. But it is not clear which carbon do D and L refer to. Could anybody let me know? Thanks.

[What are the differences between D and L glucopyranose?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/97371/what-are-the-differences-between-d-and-l-glucopyranose)

Comment: For some more context, see e.g. https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Purdue/Purdue%3A_Chem_26200%3A_Organic_Chemistry_II_(Wenthold)/Chapter_22._Carbohydrates/22.03%3A_The_D_and_L_Notation

Comment: Tbe discussions in both places are still confusing to me. I don't think they directly answer my question. So D and L do not refer to any specific carbon in glucose?

Comment: They always refer to the chiral carbon furthest from the carbonyl, so carbon 5 in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I think your confusion arises from trying to locate a particular carbon atom, which is D or L. This is not the case.

Points to remember:

The reference for D and L notation is glyceraldehye molecule not a particular carbon atom.

D and L are not equivalent to *R* and *S* which are individually applicable to each chiral center in a molecule.

Similarly, D and L cannot tell you the direction of rotation of light before hand.

Capital “D” and “L” notations have no connection with small d and small l, which tell you the direction of rotation of light.

Comment: So D and L can only be determined by experiment (or complicated computational program). This is no way that I can easily determine whether a molecule is D or L manually? So the answer by @KarstenTheis "carbon 5 in this case" is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: No, Karsten is also right. Yes, in order to assign D or L, all you need to know is the correct Fisher projection and compare it with glyceraldehyde.